# Is there a way to determine the position/size of a string in PDF using iText?

Tags: java, string, pdf, itext

so far, I've written some code that's supposed to cover text in a PDF with a white rectangle which works nicely BUT it's very static. Goal is to design it a bit more dynamically as a simple command line tool.
Is there a way to determine the position of a string within a PDF (on each page), its font size and from that calculate the rectangle size/position?
Googled quite a bit but got no satisfying answers.

Using iText. Code used so far posted below (open for optimization ideas)

```
package evaluate_java;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;

public class PDFmodifier {

    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {           
        coverWithRectangle("neu.pdf","output.pdf"); 
    }

    public static void coverWithRectangle(String input, String output)
    {
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
            int pages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(output));

            for(int i=1; i <=pages; i++)
                setContent(stamper, i, 80f, 20f, 300f, 20f, BaseColor.WHITE);

            stamper.close();
            reader.close();
            System.out.println("Success.");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            System.out.print("Failed because: ");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void setContent(PdfStamper stamp, int page,  Float x, Float y, Float width, Float height, BaseColor col)
    {
        PdfContentByte content = stamp.getOverContent(page);
        content.setColorFill(col);
        content.rectangle(x,y,width, height);
        content.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read about the classes in the iText `parser` package yet?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Hopefully not to hide the text and make it impossible to read? Depending on how you define the white, it may simply disappear in something like Adobe Acrobat and there certainly are tools out there that would let users remove your white rectangles and see what's underneath...

Comment: Just for printing so covering is fine.